# In excel, I have a time series, weekly dates and values for the particular week. I need a quick method to calculate yearly % change, i.e. YoY

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As of now, I have to manually paste the past year data, next to current year, and use the formula 100*(current-last)/last... Any shortcut ? Or built in excel function?

Below is my spreadsheet layout. I am rigidly comparing weeks 52 weeks apart.

[image]

Comment: IMO this question is not reasonably answerable without more information on the layout of your spreadsheet.The solution will probably involve a lookup (index/match/vlookup) or a sumif. Unless you are missing something obvious on just using a cell in the formula.

Comment: My table is as shown. I need to do a year on year change, for each week [link](http://s33.postimg.org/e9owgblun/Sample_table.png)

Comment: In cell D3 are you looking for a % change of the value in 1/4/2014 vs 1/x/2013 or are you comparing a running annual sum? If the former how do you choose what week to compare to (days won't match unless you force them)?

Comment: I number all weeks from 1 onwards, and use the 53 week as the reference for last year. Then I use the % difference formula. But it all gets a bit too inefficient, as I have to do it many times a day.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to why you need something more complicated. If we are looking at one big table with the layout you have shown, why can't you put in cell C56 the formula `=100*(B56-B4)/B4` ?? Nothing in your first 52 weeks of data will have a previous year to compare to.

Comment: Is the problem that you are concerned you may sort that data?